# Is it possible to reassign a mysql user variable different last_insert_ids?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Table a has a one-to-many relationship with table b.

```
table a (id)
table b (id, aId -> a.id)
```

Both table a and table b have autoincrementing ids.

I run the following statements in a single call:

```
insert into a values ();
set @id = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id);

insert into a values ();
set @id = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id);

insert into a values ();
set @id = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id);
```

...and here is the result:

```
select * from b
id  aId
1   3
2   3
3   3
```

This is not what I was expecting. Here's what I would expect to see:

```
id  aId
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

So it seems like only the last last_insert_id is used?  After some experimenting, I find I can get the results I want, if I use a different variable name after each insert.

```
insert into a values ();
set @id1 = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id1);

insert into a values ();
set @id2 = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id2);

insert into a values ();
set @id3 = last_insert_id();
insert into b (aId) values (@id3);
```

However I was hoping to just have a single variable name, and sequentially reassign it as needed.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your mysql version?, In my case, your sql is right.(Of course, your sql has some spelling error,  vlaues ==> values)

Comment: Well, it's aws rds, which is supposed to be compatible with mysql 5.7 -- maybe this is an aws bug.  (I fixed the typo!)

Comment: actually you are right, if i do it from workbench it behaves as expected -- it's only when the call is made from my nodejs mysql library that it shows the above behaviour.  Something else is going on here...

Comment: I think, you have to update the title and tag in details